# how to prevent user from deleting data in firebase realtime database in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I develop a chat application in JavaScript and write database rule in firebase. when a user send a message it push message to real time database and it works fine but problem is that user can change push to set by inspect element and send message in that case all the messages will remove , only new message add(without firebaseID).How can I prevent this problem?